# How do you use different separators in string.join in C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to write a simple code that takes a string array and joins it with 2 different separator  that alternates. What i'm looking for is if i have and array:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] {"apples","five","bananas","six","cherries","seven"};
```

I want to get a string like:

> apples=five,bananas=six,cherries=seven

It doesn't have to use just one method but the array length may vary.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the array length always even and if not how do you want it to end?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Sounds like this should be a dictionary of some sort

Comment: You will need to do the work by yourself as you are mixing semantics. What you basically try to do is two things: join tuples by = and then join the rest by ,

Comment: As others are commenting, consider re-modelling your input.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i = 0;
var result = String.Join(",",myArray.GroupBy(x=>i++/2).Select(g=>String.Join("=",g)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```
string GetJoinString(string[] data) {
    var ret = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
        var separator = i % 2 == 0 ? '=' : ',';
        ret.Append(data[i] + separator);    
    }

    return ret.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you'll need to trim a trailing separator too.

Answer (score 3):

Write your own version:

```
string Merge(string sep1, string sep2, params string[] items)
{
    string result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < items.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        result += items[i] + (i % 2 == 0 ? sep1 : sep2);
    }
    //add the last item
    result += items[items.Length - 1];

    return result;
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
string result = Merge("=", ",", myArray);
```

Comment: Never realised trim had that overload. Nice. :)

Comment: @Chris: Ha! It doesn't wih `string[]` thats why I edited, does with `char[]` though so if the Merge parameters used char then the `Trim` would work fine... actually I prefer the `char` approach so re-edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use e.g.

```
var res = myArray.Aggregate((current, next) => current + (Array.IndexOf(myArray, next) % 2 == 0 ? ",": "=") + next);
```

or without search in the array it can be

```
int index = 0;
var res = myArray.Aggregate((current, next) => current + (index++ % 2 == 0 ? "=": ",") + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = new string[] { "apples", "five", "bananas", "six", "cherries", "seven" };
var result = "";
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.Length; index = index + 2)
{
    result += string.Format("{0}={1}{2}", myArray[index], myArray[index + 1],
        index < myArray.Length - 2 ? "," : "");
}
return result;
```